# Batch - Can't put space in output of a call command

Tags: batch-file

the problem is that I can't add space after a word on the call command.

This is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=#" %%A IN ('"PROMPT #$H#$E# & ECHO ON & FOR %%B IN (1) DO REM"') DO (SET "DEL=%%A")
CALL :COLORTEXT 0B "LINE-1 "
::as you can see there is a space next of the "LINE-1" word, but the space doesn't appear as the output.
ECHO.LINE-2
PAUSE
EXIT
:COLORTEXT
<NUL SET /P ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
FINDSTR /V /A:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" NUL
DEL "%~2" > NUL 2>&1
GOTO :EOF
```

(The code after :COLORTEXT is not made by me)

Comment: The method you are using is not particularly robust, because it relies on being able to create a file named using the second argument string. This will of course restrict your intended colored text, to strings which contain only legal file names and characters. In the case above you're trying to create, read from, and delete, a file with no extension and with a trailing space. Also I'm not at all sure why you'd need to change the text color of a space character!

Comment: I just wanted make it for example:
"Hello how are you" so I can put only the word "how" with colors. I have tried a lot of things to get that done, what I am also using it "SET /p "=text" <NUL".

Thx for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trailing space being consumed is a limitation of the findstr color printing method, which due to windows file system naming conventions does not permit trailing spaces.

Here's an example of how this can be overcome:

```bat
@Echo off & PUSHD "%~dp0"
rem /* Macro Definitions */
 If "!![" == "[" (
  Echo/%%hCOL%% macro must be defined prior to delayed expansion being enabled
  Goto :end
 )
 For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")
rem /* %hCol% - color macro; No error checking. Usage: (%hCol:?=HEXVALUE%Output String) */
 Set "hCol=For %%o in (1 2)Do if %%o==2 ( <nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "!outs:\n=!" & (findstr /v /a:? /R "^$" "!outs:\n=!" nul & del "!outs:\n=!" > nul 2>&1 & Set "testout=!outs:\n=!"&If not "!testout!" == "!outs!" (Echo/)))Else Set outs="
cls
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(%hcol:?=c4%Show this output)&(%hcol:?=d1%. Follow like this)&(%hcol:?=e3%. Line break like this\n)&(%hcol:?=41%Done\n)
```

Comment: It seems confusing but I found out how it works and it's totally better than what I had before. Thanks you so much!

Comment: The files that it creates don't get deleted by themselves, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: The trailing space is ***not*** stripped by `FINDSTR`. The Windows OS does not allow trailing spaces or dots in file names - they are automatically stripped from the name.

Comment: poorly worded on my part @dbenham - updated